# Keep element scrollable until last content is reached

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure what kind of keyword should I use to ask this question, 
I already search this in Google but looks like my keyword is bad.

The problem is, I have two `div` relative element with dynamic content, meaning the height of this two element is not fixed and they are scrollable. 
Let's say the `first div` has a `class name` of `l-content` stand for `Left-Content` and the `second div` has a `class name` of `r-content` stand for `Right-Content`.

The `l-content` will have more content than the `r-content` but they will both scrollable when the screen size is not enough to show the whole content.

Now what I want to happen is when the `r-content` has reached it's last content then scrolling on it will be stop so that only the `l-content` will continue scrolling.

The Example is like on `Facebook`, as you can see where `ads`,`Recommendation`,etc are shown in the right side of it 
when the last content is reached then that element looks like fixing it's position. 
I'm not sure if it is fixing or not but I'd like my `r-content` to be like that But have no idea on how.

Current this is all i have, note that I am using Bootstrap on this:

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.l-content, .r-content {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
.l-content {
    width: 800px;
    height: 2000px;
    background: #E04C4E;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.r-content {
    width: 430px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #5996BC;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--LEFT CONTENT-->
<div class="col-lg-8 l-content">
  <h1>Left Content with Continue Scrolling.</h1>
</div>

<!--RIGHT CONTENT-->
<div class="col-lg-4 r-content">
  <h1>Right Content with Continue Scrolling but scrolling will stop when last content is reached.</h1>
</div>
```

I am not sure if it they are using a Javascript to do it.

Anyway, Thank you so much. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or bootply?

Comment: @d4rty - Here's my `jsfiddle` - https://jsfiddle.net/e1bcLxsq/2/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need javascript here, and jQuery is geared for exactly this.

scroll() and scrollTop() are the magic functions here:

```
var h = $(preceding-content).height()
var s = $('#your-sticky-element')

$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  if($(window).scrollTop() <= h){
    $(s).css({
     'position':'fixed',
     'top':'0px'
    });
  }else{
    $(s).css({
     'position':'initial'
    });
  }
}
```

This will work best if it's static content above your sticky element.  If it's updating its height in real time, you're going to be doing a lot of calculations just to keep an element in place.